# How do you pronounce "LASSO"?

Tags: terminology, lasso

Some people pronounce it "LAS-so" and some "las-SOO" (from the rope cowboys throw to catch cows). Which way is "the right one"?

Comment: I and most people I know also pronounce the rope thing a "LAS-so". Then again I've never even touched a real lasso in my life so what do I know.

Comment: I think it's a matter of regional dialect, and you can say it either way.

Comment: You're probably best off pronouncing it: `Le-ASS-Oh`. You know, "just to be on the safe side"...

Comment: The intent is to relate it to the rope thing, so presumably it should be pronounced the way you pronounce the rope-thing, but the rope-thing is pronounced either way in different varieties/dialects of English (e.g. see [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lasso) which lists both). So please yourself.

Comment: Also, I was kidding about pronouncing it `Le-ASS-Oh`...

Comment: Obviously you should pronounce it L-A-S-S-O. Trust me, I'm a statistician.

Comment: Related question: is it spelled "LASSO," "Lasso," or "lasso?" It should strictly be the first option, but Tibshirani uses "L" on his webpage and "l" in the original paper. See also: LO(W)ESS.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Hastie & Tibshirani spell it "lasso" in their newest (2015) book on the topic. See here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200416, and in particular my comments under the answer there, I give some quotes from this book.

Comment: LASS-oh is what most Americans say while la-SOO/luh-SOO is how people here [in Australia](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/features/word/search/lasso/) say.

Comment: Who cares how to pronounce it. Just use the damn thing.

Comment: I was born and raised in cow country - Southern Alberta, Canada - we pronounce it la-soo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Rob Tibshirani](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html) pronounces it the first way ("LAS-so"), which seems fairly definitive to me. However, [Trevor Hastie](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/pub.htm) pronounces it the second way ("las-SOO") and is from South Africa, so I'd agree with @Glen_b and say that any common local pronunciation of the word would be appropriate.

Comment: +1. Related comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200416/#comment380178_200418.