# How do you pronounce BOBYQA?

Tags: optimization, terminology, presentation

This question might seem subjective, but I ask because there is some [precedent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110072/how-do-you-pronounce-lasso) on this site.

I and my colleagues have always pronounced the name of this optimizer as "bobby cue ay" (which also gives it a nice friendly touch). However, when we realized what it actually stands for ("[Bound Optimization BY Quadratic Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOBYQA)") it became clear that the "BY" is not spelling anything out, but is instead a whole word. The pronounciation we've been using hides this fact.

Is "Bobby QA" an accepted pronunciation regardless, or is there some other more widely spread? Which one should I use in public when describing my work (so as to generate the least amount of giggles)?

Comment: I personally think that as a terminology issue, this is on-topic for this site. It's not as if this question would be more likely to receive an informed answer on the English Language & Usage SE, for instance. (I detest it when there are technical terms I don't know how to pronounce, for fear of looking silly when I say them, so I have sympathy for the OP here.)

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what the generally accepted pronunciation is, but I've said "*bobby-ka*" and been understood.